# Indicators Not Working when Headlights are Switched On But Work when Headlights are Switched Off. Hazard Lights Work Either Way

Tags: electrical, fiat, indicators

Vehicle: 1969 Fiat 124 Sport Spider

I have a 1969 Fiat 124 Sport Spider and am having a strange problem. The indicators are not working when the headlights are switched on but work when headlights are switched off. The hazard lights are working either way.

No fuses are blown.

I believe it is a ground issue, however I'm not sure from where I should start looking. Is it from the indicator stalk or is it something else?

Comment: If you take the headlight fuse out does turning the light switch on cause the issue? Also, is it the same on high and low beam?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!!!!  It was a ground issue.

Comment: That's awesome! I'm glad you were able to get it fixed. From what you were describing, a grounding issue was likely. The system will "find" a way to ground, and that's why some things worked some times and not at other times. Ensure you select your answer as "the answer" when you are able to.